# Why does SN1 not occur as a minor product when a strong nucleophile/strong base attacks a tertiary substrate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, elimination

The following is part of a table that appears in my Organic Chem Text (Klein)

**Nucleophile Only (e.g. Strong Nucleophile/ Weak base)**

$1^\circ - \text{ SN2}\\
2^\circ - \text{ SN1 + SN2}\\ 3^\circ - \text{ SN1}\\ $

**Strong Nucleophile/ Strong base**

$1^\circ - \text{ SN2 (maj) + E2 (min)}\\
2^\circ - \text{ SN2(min) + E2 (maj)}\\ 3^\circ - \text{E2}\\ $

Why will SN1 not also occur on tertiary substrates if the attacking nucleophile is also a strong base? That is, why doesn't it read $$3^\circ - \text{E2(maj) + SN1(min)}$$

Comment: When deciding between E2 and SN1, you could rationalize two competing key steps: deprotonation for E2, and cleavage of the leaving group for SN1 (with formation of the carbocation).

When a strong base is employed, expecially when the substrate (eg: tertiary substrate) is hindred, elimination is the only reaction which you might expect, because 1. Deprotonation is what a strong base can do very well 2. The nucleophile/base has no easy access to the electrophilic carbon atom.

Comment: @The_Vinz Thanks for your response! I understand that E2 would occur. I'm struggling with how adding the quality of "basicity" to the nucleophile stops SN1 from occurring altogether (as opposed to having both occur with SN1 the minor product). I don't understand your reasoning employing steric hindrance as my book repeatedly employs the reasoning that this is not relevant for Loss of a LG (and according SN1 as the carbocat is planar).

Comment: You should consider that in case of a strong nucleophile/strong base, the nucleophile is so reactive that it is unlikely to allow the formation of a separate carbocation: any reaction you expect is concerted (e2, sn2).

Comment: Acid-base reactions should be faster with a strong base present. Think about what the molecules are trying to do in the rate-determining step. The base only needs to access a tiny proton sticking out. A strong base that's actively searching for something to deprotonate will do this rapidly. Furthermore, in a tertiary substrate there can also be a statistical preponderance of sites to deprotonate. Meanwhile, in SN1, the LG has to ponder whether it's a nice day to leave the house, then do his stretching, and finally walk far enough away so that another squatter can slip in and occupy the house.

Comment: I think if you took a real example i.e., choose a model substrate and try doing the reaction in the lab, you may actually observe some substitution product (presumably via a SN1 route). My guess would be that if you tried to quantify the relative amount of the substitution product you've produced (eg.using 1H NMR), it will be less than 10%... maybe <1%, or 'trace'. It may be only meaningful to talk about 'minor' products when they are in at least some, substantial (though minor) quantity! It will also depend on the temperature at which you do your reaction.